# Server Affecting HTML

Tags: jboss, html, wildfly

I have inherited responsibility for an old web application that currently running on JBoss7. I've been tasked with migrating it to Wildfly 9.

I've noticed though the web pages display fine on JBoss 7 but they don't display well when the application runs on Wildfly 9. It seems that most, if not all, of these issues are HTML5 related issues (e.g. table alignments, etc).

But I'm wondering why and how does the server affect what is displayed on the web page? I have the exact same code and display it in the exact same browser (in this case IE11). The only difference is the server. Why would the server affect the web page display?

Comment: @RolandStarke no, nothing else is different. i simply start up using JBoss7 or Wildfly 9. Same DB connection; same data; same everything. The only difference is the server. I'm sure there are different settings in WF9 vs JB7. But I don't understand why/how they would affect presentation. Isn't that the browser's job?

Comment: Seems like it should be the browsers responsibility. Maybe check the headers for differences. I'm not sure how that would affect it though. Have you tried WIldFly 10 by chance?